# Error creating class with properties in the constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have created this class:

```
export class ModelTransformer {
  constructor(private readonly hostelTransformer: HostelTransformer) {}

  static transform(hostel: Hostel): Hotel {
    return hostelTransformer.transform(hostel);
  }
}
```

But when I compile it I have this compilation error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'hostelTransformer'.

I also tried

```
 static transform(hostel: Hostel): Hotel {
        return this.hostelTransformer.transform(hostel);
      }
```

but then I have the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'hostelTransformer' does not exist on type 'typeof ModelTransformer'.
```

Comment: There's no `this` for a static method (no instance, that is, `this` refers to the class), that's pretty much the point of static methods and properties. Why do you declare `transform` as static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access the *instance* properties inside static methods.

When you use `private readonly hostelTransformer: HostelTransformer` in the constructor, it goes on the instance of the `ModelTransformer` class. Like this

```js
constructor(hostelTransformer) {
  this.hostelTransformer = hostelTransformer;
}
```

You can't use `return this.hostelTransformer.transform(hostel)` because `transform` is a static method. When you call `ModelTransformer.transform()`, `this` will be `ModelTransformer` and not the instance of the class.

If you want to use that property, you need to make the method non-static